# Structured data in Django

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.6**

Could you tell me what is the Django way of implementing structured data.
I have an information site. And I may need any type of structured data: either present or appearing in future.

I mean this: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

I append articles through admin only. In other words users don't generate articles, they just comment.

Structured data may be a big insertion to a page. Even in the above linked page an example is trimmed for brevity. And there may be more content types in future. So, maybe it is not reasonable to burden models with such information.

I can only think of a safe template tag. 
In the middle of articles structured data will be inserted, say, as a JSON-LD structured data.

Could you tell me what are best practices here.